# Why is being LGBT a sin in Islam?

Tags: homosexuality

Muslim LGBT people are also human. They have feelings: love, hate, happy and sadness. Why is being LGBT a sin in Islam?

In my opinion, Allah and true, and Islam doesn't prohibit LGBT. Because each person has their own reason that Allah bring us to this world.  And if being LGBT is a sin, Allah will punish them. But, why Allah doesn't punish them? Because they also are human.

And the most important of one person Muslim are there: **good mind, pure heart (including love) and the believe in Allah/God** by doing 5 pillar of Islam.

And if the LGBT Muslims and all LGBT people in the world in have good mind, pure heart and believe in Allah, I think they will be forgiven by Allah.  You can see the proof in the daily life. Some people are LGBT and homosexual, but they have a beautiful love story, just as some other heterosexual couples and they have a happy life. I think that is a gift from Allah, because their love is pure love.

But some LGBT people encounter trouble: I think that is the challenge from Allah to them. If they have a strong love and the pure heart, Allah will help them passed. I think Muslims should have a better look of LGBT and homosexual people. And Allah will bless everybody if we rise to love and do good for the world (subtract the bad people).

Comment: This question will easily be flagged. Please review [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://example.com)

Comment: LGB and T are different... one question doesnot cover them all.

Answer (score 0):

Assalam alaikum,
Allah created the world and presented the man with a thought process which defines right from wrong. It is this thought process which tell you whether a certain activity is a legitimate thing to do or not.

Now when we talk about earning money, we know that stealing, robbing, looting, black-marketing are all wrong ways. How? It comes from within.

Allah has created lawful ways for all the needs that we have in this world. Similarly, Allah has created lawful ways for our sexual desires. And Allah clearly mentions n the Quran LGB are unlawful.

Coming back to your statement

> And the most important of one person Muslim are there: good mind, pure heart(inculed the love) and the believe in Allah/God by doing 5 pillar of Islam**.And if the LGBT Muslim and all LGBT in the world in have good mind, pure heart and believe in Allah, i think them will be forgive by Allah.

We cannot say for sure that even the most righteous person will be forgiven by Allah, if Allah doesn't wish it. 
Even our Prophet Muhammed( s.a.w.) mentioned once( sorry i dont remember the reference of the hadith) that "No one will enter paradise if Allah doesn't wills." One of the companions(r.a.) asked,"Ya Rasoolallah, Is it even applicable to you?". Prophet(s.a.w.) replied, "Yes, even me".

This is a test for the person who has such desires. Like you said

> But some LGBT people have been get trouble, i think that is the challenge from Allah to them.

All we can do is strive to be our best. Repent if we fail and resolve never to repeat it again. InshaAllah, Allah will help us pass with distinction.

Hope it helped.